# django - queryset include element at start of each result row

Tags: django

I have a query that returns results like so -

```
[{'trgjob_id': 22659, 'trgmst_id': 'Tidal - Default Email Abnormal', 'jobmst_id': 10081, 'trgjob_order': 1, 'trgjob_type': 0, 'trgjob_level': 0}, 
{'trgjob_id': 29054, 'trgmst_id': 'CADIS - DMS Email Abnormal ', 'jobmst_id': 10081, 'trgjob_order': 2, 'trgjob_type': 0, 'trgjob_level': 0}, 
{'trgjob_id': 29055, 'trgmst_id': 'CADIS - DMS Email Error ', 'jobmst_id': 10081, 'trgjob_order': 3, 'trgjob_type': 0, 'trgjob_level': 0}]
```

What I would like it to do is add the model name - `trgjob` at the beginning of each result (there's 3 results here).  How do I go about doing that?

Putting it at the beginning of all the results is easy I just do this -

```
{'trgjob': trgjobstring.data}
```

edit in the example above I want it to look like this -

```
['trgjob': 
    {'trgjob_id': 22659, 'trgmst_id': 'Tidal - Default Email Abnormal', 'jobmst_id': 10081, 'trgjob_order': 1, 'trgjob_type': 0, 'trgjob_level': 0},
'trgjob': 
    {'trgjob_id': 29054, 'trgmst_id': 'CADIS - DMS Email Abnormal ', 'jobmst_id': 10081, 'trgjob_order': 2, 'trgjob_type': 0, 'trgjob_level': 0},
'trgjob':
    {'trgjob_id': 29055, 'trgmst_id': 'CADIS - DMS Email Error ', 'jobmst_id': 10081, 'trgjob_order': 3, 'trgjob_type': 0, 'trgjob_level': 0}]
```

If the syntax doesn't look right I apologize.  I don't actually know how it's "supposed" to look but I know I want the data at the beginning of each row.

edit -

I have a custom serializer that is dumping this data into XML and right now it's formatting it in a way I don't want (regardless of if it's correct or not).

```
<list-item>
    <list-item>
        <trgjob_id>245970</trgjob_id>
        <trgmst_id>nope</trgmst_id>
        <jobmst_id>34614</jobmst_id>
        <trgjob_order>1</trgjob_order>
        <trgjob_type>0</trgjob_type>
        <trgjob_level>0</trgjob_level>
    </list-item>
    <list-item>
        <trgjob_id>245969</trgjob_id>
        <trgmst_id>blah</trgmst_id>
        <jobmst_id>34614</jobmst_id>
        <trgjob_order>2</trgjob_order>
        <trgjob_type>0</trgjob_type>
        <trgjob_level>0</trgjob_level>
    </list-item>
</list-item>
```

so 1.  I need list-item to be the 'trgjob' as I have in the original ask.

1. I don't want 2 levels of list-item.

I want the XML to look like this -

```
    <trgjob>
        <trgjob_id>245970</trgjob_id>
        <trgmst_id>nope</trgmst_id>
        <jobmst_id>34614</jobmst_id>
        <trgjob_order>1</trgjob_order>
        <trgjob_type>0</trgjob_type>
        <trgjob_level>0</trgjob_level>
    </trgjob>
    <trgjob>
        <trgjob_id>245969</trgjob_id>
        <trgmst_id>blah</trgmst_id>
        <jobmst_id>34614</jobmst_id>
        <trgjob_order>2</trgjob_order>
        <trgjob_type>0</trgjob_type>
        <trgjob_level>0</trgjob_level>
    </trgjob>
```

The closest I've gotten to this is by removing "list-item" from the renderer and altering the view but I currently only know how to put the "trgjob" at the beginning of all results not at the beginning of each one.

Comment: I can't find a reason why you would need to do that. Can you explain why?

Comment: I when the results go to my custom serializer I need it to separate it so it's not showing all the values under one list but separately.  I'll update my ask.

Comment: are you asking how to access the model name from a given object?

Comment: Also, wouldn't it make more sense to have it `{'trgjob': [QuerySet of items]}` instead of repeating it 3 times?

Comment: Seeing your edit, your question makes a lot more sense. May I suggest you show us the code for you serializer (or what tool you used) and we'll help you understand how to use it the way you want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question well, this is how I would do it:

```
In [1]: qs_results = [{'trgjob_id': 22659, 'trgmst_id': 'Tidal - Default Email Abnormal', 'jobmst_id': 10081, 'trgjob_order': 1, 'trgjob_type': 0, 'trgjob_level': 0}, 
   ...: {'trgjob_id': 29054, 'trgmst_id': 'CADIS - DMS Email Abnormal ', 'jobmst_id': 10081, 'trgjob_order': 2, 'trgjob_type': 0, 'trgjob_level': 0}, 
   ...: {'trgjob_id': 29055, 'trgmst_id': 'CADIS - DMS Email Error ', 'jobmst_id': 10081, 'trgjob_order': 3, 'trgjob_type': 0, 'trgjob_level': 0}]

In [2]: client_results = [{'trgjob':item} for item in qs_results]

In [3]: client_results
Out[3]: 
[{'trgjob': {'jobmst_id': 10081,
   'trgjob_id': 22659,
   'trgjob_level': 0,
   'trgjob_order': 1,
   'trgjob_type': 0,
   'trgmst_id': 'Tidal - Default Email Abnormal'}},
 {'trgjob': {'jobmst_id': 10081,
   'trgjob_id': 29054,
   'trgjob_level': 0,
   'trgjob_order': 2,
   'trgjob_type': 0,
   'trgmst_id': 'CADIS - DMS Email Abnormal '}},
 {'trgjob': {'jobmst_id': 10081,
   'trgjob_id': 29055,
   'trgjob_level': 0,
   'trgjob_order': 3,
   'trgjob_type': 0,
   'trgmst_id': 'CADIS - DMS Email Error '}}]
```

The key is in line 2 which adds a key for each dict item in queryset results `qs_results`.

Comment: I find this a bad answer, not because it's wrong, but because while that'd be a good solution for python, it isn't good django code

Comment: Thank you Josvic!  This has done what I want.  I can continue customizing my view now.  Trying to match a legacy applications output.

Comment: A list comprehension in django means a [lot more queries to the database](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6714479/2387772). It's better to find a way to use the [django ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/). Even though in the OP's code he already fetches the info into a list, you can probably fetch the entire thing into the desired format straight away (not to mention there's probably a better less repetative way to work with his serializer and he just doesn't realize it)

Comment: @yuvi I agree with you, but that would be [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Re XML serialization; that's new isn't it? If the data is to be serialized then the most effective way depends on the xml serialization part, which is outside this question's original topic.

Comment: That's why I commented on the OP question asking to see the serializer itself, and why I think a technically working solution isn't necessarily a good one.

Answer (score 1):

keep it lazy:

```
for item in qs_results:
    yield {'trgjob':item}
```

Comment: That should be a comment on my answer. You even use the variable name I use in my answer ;) Did not downvote your answer though since it's still a good answer.